# VPN Leak Test Results understanding

Tags: linux, vpn, operating-systems

I just set up a new VPN on Ubuntu server... I did a leak test on https://dnsleaktest.com/ (My default DNS is google DNS) and It came up with alot of servers when I did the extended test. Is the more Servers that show up the more better and secure?

Answer (score 0):

The point of a VPN is to secure your connection to another network (or the internet). The DNS leak test is allegedly telling you who is servicing your DNS requests. The idea is that, if it shows any request being served from a source not controlled by the VPN service, you might have a security issue in the sense that somebody, potentially untrusted, knows what you're looking at based on your DNS requests.